# Get Notified that DB is updated and update feed

Tags: java, python, mysql, servlets

In **`mysql`** is there a way i can get notified about that a table has been updated with this much amount of rows ?
well i need to perform a task to update xml/json feed automatically whyen there is an update in the database .

i searched for few things like calling triggers ,[calling a java method from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034631/how-to-call-java-code-from-mysql)  also [get notification in python i have checked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771925/python-how-to-get-notifications-for-mysql-database-changes) but i was looking for an approach where less java work will be required to do .doing it from a servlet was an idea for me but doing it from mysql will be good..

any ideas guys ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a random though, maybe you could do it in your server instead? It seems like you want a simple way rather than a efficent way. I'd recommend trying something like cronjob in linux. Simply make a script in your DB server that query for changes every once and a while, and send some sort of notification(mail?) out when changes detected? I have no idea how complex your script needs to be in order to detect the changes you want, so this might not be the best idea

edit: so basically you want to edit external files with triggers, then maybe UDF is the thing you need.

take a look at [this blog](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.hk/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) and see if that's what you want.

Comment: if i have to perform script i could have done it using servlets ,that will be an equivalnet efforts ..to hit on servlet and check for a variable in db such that its updated or not .but i need somthing efficiet not eazy one.

Comment: then what's wrong with triggers? are they not good enough? what do you want that triggers can't provide?